# On/Off FlipSwitch in CSS not working as an Angular 2 Component

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I am trying to create a re-usable flip switch component as

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "bm-input-switch",
    templateUrl: "./bm-input-switch.component.html",
    styleUrls:['bm-input-switch.component.css']
})
export class BmInputSwitchComponent {

    @Input()
    name: string;

    @Input()
    id: string;

    @Input()
    labelText: string;

    @Input()
    checked :boolean;
}
```

**HTML** bm-input-switch.component.html:

```
<div>
    <div class="onoffswitch">
        <input type="checkbox" [name]="name" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" [id]="id">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" [for]="id">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** bm-input-switch.component.css

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    -ms-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0;
    -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0;
    -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0;
}

    .onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: white;
        font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .onoffswitch-inner:before {
        content: "YES";
        padding-left: 10px;
        background-color: #1C456B;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .onoffswitch-inner:after {
        content: "NO";
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: #EEEEEE;
        color: #999999;
        text-align: right;
    }

.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block;
    width: 27px;
    margin: 1.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999;
    -ms-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px;
}
```

**USAGE**

```
<bm-input-switch id="gaVersion" name="gaVersion" labelText="GA Version" checked="false"></bm-input-switch>
```

However, it is not changing the state on click.
If I do not use it as component and just try to run in static page, it then works.

Any Ideas ?
Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/hdNI02Eywx1xsHTn9tSA?p=preview

Comment: What's the exact problem , Can you share the snippet for error cause at https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview , this is working fine.

Comment: @HG-1221 I have created the plunk here : https://plnkr.co/edit/hdNI02Eywx1xsHTn9tSA?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input variables on the switch component are confusing the "for" attribute. If you look at the generated html, you'll have two elements with the same id. Also, don't use the square brackets for native DOM attributes, just use the curly braces.

Check out this new plnkr with a working switch. https://plnkr.co/edit/isecXgfkU3K93GIxtviP?p=preview

I've just changed your "id" and "name" variables to "switchId" and "switchName", and also changed the [id] and [name] bindings to use curly brackets inside your switch component html.

Your new switch component:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "bm-input-switch",
    templateUrl: "bm-input-switch.component.html",
    styleUrls:['bm-input-switch.component.css']
})
export class BmInputSwitchComponent {

    @Input()
    switchName: string;

    @Input()
    switchId: string;

    @Input()
    labelText: string;

    @Input()
    checked :boolean;
}
```

Your switch component html:

```
<div>
  <div>{{labelText}}</div>
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{switchName}}" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="{{switchId}}">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="{{switchId}}">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And calling it:

```
<h1>Switch Example</h1>
<div>
   <bm-input-switch switchId="autoCreate" switchName="autocreate" labelText="Auto Create" checked="false"></bm-input-switch>
</div>

<bm-input-switch switchId="displayCode" switchName="displayCode" labelText="Display Code" checked="false"></bm-input-switch>
```